# Align equal signs too much spacing in cases

Tags: spacing, align, cases

I am trying to write two equations that will be aligned at the equal signs and also connected together at the left with a curly bracket (like a piecewise definition), but when I use the `\begin{cases}` environment simultaneously with the `amsmath`'s `\begin{align*}` environment, there seems to be a blank space added to the left of the equal signs, which I do not want (and does not appear with the `\begin{align*}` environment alone…)

```
    \begin{align*}
    \begin{cases}
    \dot{x} &= f(x) \\
    x(0)&=x_0
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
```

Results for me in:

[image]

though I would prefer the spacing as seen here using only the `\begin{align*}` environment (referring to the spacing to the left of the equal signs):

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x} &= f(x) \\
x(0) &= x_0
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now compare with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = f(x) \\
x(0) = x_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe that the latter format is better.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `empheq` package (needless to load `amsmath` in this case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
\dot x & = f(x)\\%
x(0) & = x_0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't require loading any packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} l}
  \dot{x} & f(x) \\
  x(0)    & x_0
\end{array}
\right.
\]  
\end{document}
```